# How can I bypass or detect SSL Certificate before the message is shown in Adobe AIR?

Tags: apache-flex, air, ssl-certificate

"The SSL Certificate is not trusted." dialog occurs in Adobe AIR application.
How can I detect this situation before it happens?
(Actually I want my app to bypass the warning...)

Please check the following code:

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest('http://bit.ly/dzKg2q');
request.followRedirects = true;
request.manageCookies = true;
request.useCache = true;
request.authenticate = false;    // I set this as true, but it does not work either.

var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader;

loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(event:Event):void {
    trace('COMPLETE');
});
loader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, function(event:Event):void {
    trace('SECURITY_ERROR');
});
loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, function(event:Event):void {
    trace('IO_ERROR');
});


try{
    loader.load(request);
}catch(e:SecurityError) {
    trace(e);
}
```

Thank you very much for your attention.

Comment: I would doubt that this is even possible.  Wouldn't that defeat the purpose of having security in the first place?

Comment: Indeed.  The only way to bypass the warning would be to make it a trusted certificate.  You can do that by installing the site's certificate in the list of trusted certificates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to prevent this error "At the source".

Have a valid SSL Certificate from a known certificate authority installed on the server for the domain you are trying to access.

I doubt there is any valid way to suppress this error

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I solve this problem in another way - tracing all redirection.

Comment: I don't actually understand what "Tracing All Redirection" means.  But, you should post your own answer as an answer and mark then accept your own answer

Comment: I didn't use auto redirection. "request.followRedirects = false;" and manually make redirection by checking HTTPStatusEvent.responseHeaders to judge whether the url is https or http.